# Why am I getting a NullPointerException When Attempting To Place a Marker on GoogleMap?

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, google-maps-markers

I'm having problems getting Google Map SDK to display inside a fragment on my Kotlin android project.

Sometimes the map will display, other times it wont. I might run the app (green play button Android Studio) one time, it'll work, close and run it again, and it will crash, despite no changes to the code itself.

Attempting to place a map marker has also often crashed the app, again sometimes it'll display, othertimes it'll crash...

Here's the fragment code:

```
class global_map : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback{

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_global_map, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val mapFragment: SupportMapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }
    

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
       mMap = googleMap
        mMap.addMarker(
            MarkerOptions().position(LatLng(0.0, 0.0)).title("Test")
        )
    }
}
```

In terms of data from Logcat, please find this below:

```
2021-10-11 14:31:34.747 6751-6751/co.uk.myapp.app W/Resources: Drawable com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite:drawable/maps_watermark_color has unresolved theme attributes! Consider using Resources.getDrawable(int, Theme) or Context.getDrawable(int).
    java.lang.RuntimeException
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:899)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.ax.m(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213614097@21.36.14 (150400-0):5)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fh.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213614097@21.36.14 (150400-0):3)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bo.az(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213614097@21.36.14 (150400-0):16)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.cr.o(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213614097@21.36.14 (150400-0):2)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.o.aX(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213614097@21.36.14 (150400-0):22)
        at dx.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213614097@21.36.14 (150400-0):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1043)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzH(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzk.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzau.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zad.zaa(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(Unknown Source:9)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreateView(Unknown Source:25)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:1)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:3065)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2988)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3138)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:502)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8024)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3475)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
2021-10-11 14:31:34.747 6751-6751/co.uk.myapp.app W/Resources:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2021-10-11 14:31:34.774 6751-6751/co.uk.myapp.app W/Resources: Drawable com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite:drawable/maps_btn_myl has unresolved theme attributes! Consider using Resources.getDrawable(int, Theme) or Context.getDrawable(int).
    java.lang.RuntimeException
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:899)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.ax.m(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213614097@21.36.14 (150400-0):5)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.w.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213614097@21.36.14 (150400-0):8)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bo.az(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213614097@21.36.14 (150400-0):20)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.cr.o(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213614097@21.36.14 (150400-0):2)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.o.aX(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213614097@21.36.14 (150400-0):22)
        at dx.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213614097@21.36.14 (150400-0):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1043)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzH(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzk.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzau.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zad.zaa(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(Unknown Source:9)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreateView(Unknown Source:25)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:1)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:3065)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2988)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3138)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:502)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8024)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3475)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
2021-10-11 14:31:34.775 6751-6751/co.uk.myapp.app W/Resources:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2021-10-11 14:31:34.784 6751-6751/co.uk.myapp.app W/Resources: Drawable com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite:drawable/maps_btn_zoom_down has unresolved theme attributes! Consider using Resources.getDrawable(int, Theme) or Context.getDrawable(int).
    java.lang.RuntimeException
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:899)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.ax.m(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213614097@21.36.14 (150400-0):5)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.w.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213614097@21.36.14 (150400-0):30)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bo.az(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213614097@21.36.14 (150400-0):20)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.cr.o(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213614097@21.36.14 (150400-0):2)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.o.aX(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213614097@21.36.14 (150400-0):22)
        at dx.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213614097@21.36.14 (150400-0):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1043)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzH(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzk.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzau.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zad.zaa(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(Unknown Source:9)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreateView(Unknown Source:25)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@17.0.1:1)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:3065)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2988)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3138)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:502)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8024)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3475)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
2021-10-11 14:31:34.784 6751-6751/co.uk.myapp.app W/Resources:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2021-10-11 14:31:34.932 6751-6774/co.uk.myapp.app W/AdrenoUtils: <ReadGpuID_from_sysfs:197>: Failed to open /sys/class/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/gpu_model
2021-10-11 14:31:34.932 6751-6774/co.uk.myapp.app W/AdrenoUtils: <ReadGpuID:221>: Failed to read chip ID from gpu_model. Fallback to use the GSL path
2021-10-11 14:31:35.014 6751-6774/co.uk.myapp.app W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
2021-10-11 14:31:35.020 6751-6816/co.uk.myapp.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 24197
    Process: co.uk.myapp.app, PID: 6751
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.aj.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213614097@21.36.14 (150400-0):11)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.aj.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213614097@21.36.14 (150400-0):3)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.g.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213614097@21.36.14 (150400-0):18)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bs.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213614097@21.36.14 (150400-0):14)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.av.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213614097@21.36.14 (150400-0):45)
2021-10-11 14:31:35.028 1500-2253/? W/ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity co.uk.myapp.app/.MainActivity
```

Comment: Since the NPE is internal to the API class, we need to see more of your stack trace.

Comment: Thanks @Tenfour04 , I have included more data from logcat. I have my API key in manifest, I have `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'` in my Gradle, I have followed numerous tutorials on YouTube and the Google Documentation (which is for Activity rather than Fragment), yet I still get many problems.

Comment: It's annoying because occasionally it'll work once when I run it and then if I apply changes and build it again, it crashes thereafter

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be the source of your problem. Just a guess.

Since the map is created asynchronously, it is possible `onMapReady` is called while the Fragment is in detached state, in which case there would be no associated Context and Theme for the map view to use. Maybe that is causing it the error retrieving its drawable resources. I would change your code as follows:

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    context ?: return // Fragment has been detached--don't do anything.
    mMap = googleMap
    mMap.addMarker(
        MarkerOptions().position(LatLng(0.0, 0.0)).title("Test")
    )
}
```

or alternatively:

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    if (isDetached) return
    mMap = googleMap
    mMap.addMarker(
        MarkerOptions().position(LatLng(0.0, 0.0)).title("Test")
    )
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. That would certainly explain why sometimes it works on build, and other times it doesn't. I'll report back soon

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error, NPE relating to the drawables. I'll try the code on another of my projects and see if it does the same.

Comment: if it helps, the app actually resumes working perfectly if I clear the app's cache. If I use "Apply Changes and Restart Activty" in Android Studio, it causes it to crash again (until cache is cleared)

Comment: Oh, that is completely expected! “Apply changes and restart” only sometimes works because it’s trying to hot-swap code without recompiling it. Any change that affects resources will cause it to fail to work. There are other types of changes that will cause it to fail as well, such as adding or removing a property from a class or changing a function signature. This is documented in the developer guide for Android Studio. Most of the time you should use Run so it rebuilds your app. Apply changes is for tiny trivial changes in Java/Kotlin code only.

Comment: Ok thankyou very much, I was worrying about having to keep clearing my cache and any users having to as well if I ever released it on play store.